# Where is my unexpected token error occurring?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

friends. I'm getting a syntax error, that is pointing at the closing curly bracket just above the render. It says that it's expecting a comma, but I don't understand why. All of the curly brackets have opening and closing brackets. What am I missing?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


class List extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            sports: []
        }


    }

componentWillMount(){
    axios.get('my url is in here')
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                sports: response
            })
        }
    }

    render(){


        return(
            <div>
                <p>{this.state.sports} </p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default List;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a right parenthesis:

```js
componentWillMount(){
  axios.get('my url is in here')
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        sports: response
      })
    }) // <-- this )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to close the `.then()` as follows:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('my url is in here').then(response => {
      this.setState({
        sports: response,
      });
    }); //<--- here, a ) is needed
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


class List extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            sports: []
        }


    }

componentWillMount(){

    axios.get('my url is in here')
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                sports: response
            })
        })
    }

    render(){


        return(
            <div>
                <p>{this.state.sports} </p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default List;




your updated code..

you just miss the closing bracket in  componentWillMount() method.

componentWillMount(){

  axios.get('my url is in here')

    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        sports: response
      })enter code here
    }) // <-- this )
  }
}
```

Comment: You should use `getDerivedstatefromprops` instead of `componentWillMount` since it had been removed in 16.4.